# No fancybox scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a problem with fancybox scrollbar. Fancybox just usesbrowser scrollbar. I need the fixed height of fancybox and scrollbar in the fancybox popup.

http://prntscr.com/4hgcci

My html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.jscrollpane.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fancy').fancybox({
                type:'image',
                fitToView: false,
                width: '90%',
                height: '90%',
                autoSize: false,

        }
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<a id= "fancy" href="landing_v2.jpg"><img width="200" src="landing_v2.jpg"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve what you want when fancybox `type` of `content` is `image`, however as a workaround, you can set it as `html` and recompose the `content` using the `beforeLoad` callback like :

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function () {
        this.content = "<img src='" + this.href + "' alt='' />"
    },
    type: "html"
});
```

Optionally, you can set the fixed `height` you want combining `height` with `maxHeight` API options.

Also make sure your images are responsive adding this CSS declaration :

```
img { max-width: 100% }
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yhsv2q8x/)**